# modifying a field while pattern matching on it

Tags: pointers, pattern-matching, rust

I tried my hands at Rust for the first time today (writing a XML tokenizer), and naturally don’t understand everything:

I have a struct with field that can take an enum value:

```
enum State { Outside, InATag(~str) }
struct Tokenizer { state: State }
```

In a `impl Tokenizer`, I want to match on the current state, and change it in some cases, however this always gives a `use of moved value` error.

H to access and/or declare the state field so that I can match on it and change its value inside a match branch?

---

Sorry for the confusion, I meant to change the Tokenizer’s state field, not the state’s String field!

```
match self.state {
    InATag(name) => self.state = Outside,
    Outside => ()
}
```

Comment: what version of Rust are you using ?

Comment: The Rust language is changing fast, syntax and semantics are not fixed, yet. In particular, I'm pretty sure that the behavior of `match` changed recently (or will change, maybe in 0.7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, with the clarified variant of the question, here is my revised answer:

```
enum State { Outside, InATag(~str) }
struct Tokenizer { state: State }

impl Tokenizer {
    fn toggle(&mut self) {
        match self {
            &Tokenizer { state: InATag(*) } => { self.state = Outside }
            &Tokenizer { state: Outside }   => { self.state = InATag(~"baz") }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut t1 = Tokenizer { state: InATag(~"foo") };
    match t1 {
        Tokenizer { state: InATag(*) } => { t1.state = Outside }
        Tokenizer { state: Outside } => { /* impossible */ }
    }
    io::println(fmt!("Hello t1: %?", t1));
    let mut t2 = Tokenizer { state: InATag(~"bar") };
    t2.toggle();
    io::println(fmt!("World t2: %?", t2));
}
```

I admit, I actually did not expect it to be as easy as the above, and I can easily believe that small changes to the above code could cause it to start failing to borrow-check.  But without a more fleshed out example from the asker, it is hard to tell whether the above code would suit his purposes or not.

Oh, here's the output when I compile and run the code:

```
% rustc /tmp/m.rs
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
% /tmp/m
Hello t1: {state: Outside}
World t2: {state: Outside}
%
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! so it needs a mutable pointer to self in the method, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 6):

Without a more concrete example, it is hard to tell whether this would solve your problem, but you can use `ref` within a match pattern to make a reference to the matched substructure, and you can use `ref mut` to make that reference mutable.

So, in your example:

```
enum State { Outside, InATag(~str) }
struct Tokenizer { state: State }

fn main() {
    let mut t = Tokenizer { state: InATag(~"foo") };
    match t.state {
         InATag(ref mut _s)  => { *_s = ~"bar"; }
         Outside => { /* impossible */ }
    }
    io::println(fmt!("Hello World: %?", t));
}
```

or if you need to match other parts of the Tokenizer state, this works too:

```
fn main() {
    let mut t = Tokenizer { state: InATag(~"foo") };
    match t {
        Tokenizer { state: InATag(ref mut _s) } => { *_s = ~"bar"; }
        Tokenizer { state: Outside } => { /* impossible */ }
    }
    io::println(fmt!("Hello World: %?", t));
}
```

Note that when doing this sort of code, it can be pretty easy to inadvertently run into borrow-check violations due to aliasing.  For example, here is a relatively small change to the second example above that *won't* compile:

```
fn main() {
    let mut t = Tokenizer { state: InATag(~"foo") };
    match &t {
        &Tokenizer { state: InATag(ref mut _s) } => { *_s = ~"bar"; }
        &Tokenizer { state: Outside } => { /* impossible */ }
    }
    io::println(fmt!("Hello World: %?", t));
}
```

causes the following message from rustc:

```
/tmp/m.rs:7:35: 7:46 error: illegal borrow: creating mutable alias to enum content
/tmp/m.rs:7         &Tokenizer { state: InATag(ref mut _s) } => { *_s = ~"bar"; }
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

because you do not want an outstanding borrow `&t` while you are also creating mutable aliases to the internals of `t`

Comment: This answer certainly helps me to understand more of Rust, but I seem to have expressed myself poorly: I want to switch the state, not modify its value. sorry for the confusion! I update my question accordingly.