# modify field of a struct while pattern matching on it

Tags: rust

In my code, I have a struct which stores messages for users in a HashMap called `messages`. Inside a function which takes `&mut self` as an arguement,  when I find messages for the user, I would like to modify the value of this field to remove these messages, so that the user doesn't get the same messages twice. However, I get the error that I can't borrow self as mutable because I've borrowed it as immutable at the start of the pattern match.

```
match self.messages.find(&username) {
             Some(message_array) => {
               //do some stuff to send the messages
               self.messages.remove(&username);
             },
```

I found this question [modifying a field while pattern matching on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289880/modifying-a-field-while-pattern-matching-on-it), but the accepted answer for it doesn't seem to address my question -- I don't understand how the line `&Tokenizer { state: InATag(*) } => { self.state = Outside }` makes self mutable again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust provides `HashMap::pop` to make what you want easy:

```
match self.messages.pop(&username) {
    Some(message_array) => {
        // do some stuff to send the messages
        // entry for &username is already removed
    },
```

You aren't really modifying a field of a struct while matching on it, you're matching on the result of `find` and trying to modify the underlying hashtable, which Rust won't let you do because then the `message_array` reference wouldn't point to a valid location anymore. It would be possible to modify `message_array` itself however using `find_mut`:

```
match self.messages.find_mut(&username) {
    Some(message_array) => {
        // do some stuff to send the messages
        message_array.truncate(0) // remove all messages
    },
```

Comment: +1 for almost complete agreement. I just don't know what you meant by "reference wouldn't point to a valid location anymore". `find` just returns an `Option<&'a V>` which possibly contains an immutable reference and for obvious reasons, Rust does not allow us to use an immutable reference as a mutable one.

Comment: @sellibitze OP wanted to modify the hashtable, not what `message_array` pointed to. The reference returned by `find` points into the hashtable, so it represents an immutable borrowing of the hashtable. `remove` would need to make a (separate) mutable borrowing, which the borrow checker won't allow. If the borrow checker didn't stop this then `remove` might destroy or modify the location that `message_array` points to, which wouldn't be safe.